# Meteor.js Browserify error using an npm module with meteorhacks:npm and browserify

Tags: node.js, meteor, reactjs, npm

Browserify file (client/app.browserify.js):

react-typist = require('react-typist');

packages.json:

```
{
  "redis": "0.8.2",
  "github": "0.1.8",
  "react-typist": "0.3.0"
}
```

I am receiving this error:

Browserify error:

```
While processing files with cosmos:browserify (for target web.browser):
client/app.browserify.js: Parsing file /Users/*********/www/app-react/packages/npm-container/.npm/package/_stream_0.js: Assigning to rvalue (1:0)

Browserify options:
>  {
>  "basedir": "/Users/***********/www/app-react/packages/npm-container/.npm/package",
>  "debug": true,
>  "transforms": {}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
react-typist = require('react-typist');
```

is not valid when assigning variable. It should be

```
Typist = require('react-typist');
```

Comment: try to comment that line. If you still have error, then you have some garbage files need to be cleared

Comment: oh it looks like I had two browserify files for some reason, it's now working.  How do I use this in one of my jsx files now?

Comment: you already define it as global. just go back to your previous code in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35736983/using-npm-modules-with-meteor-js-1-2-1-with-meteorhacks to see if it works now

Comment: So, I am getting: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderMsg' of null

Comment: dude, go to that bug and put the comment there

Comment: sorry, noob questions I know, just a different way of thinking about these packages.  And this was the example given by the package verbatim, so not sure why any of it isn't working.

Comment: While processing files with cosmos:browserify (for target web.cordova):
   packages/rocketchat:wangeditor/wangEditor.browserify.js: Unexpected token
   
   Browserify options:
   >  {
   >  "transforms": {},
   >  "basedir":
   "/Users/apple/meteorProject/Rocket.Chat/packages/rocketchat-wangeditor/.npm/package",
   >  "debug": true
   }
   
   Special options:
   >  {}
   
=> Your application has errors. Waiting for file change.

Comment: i just flow https://github.com/elidoran/cosmos-browserify-example/tree/master/package write a package user npm module， my package.js ->Package.onUse(function(api) {
  api.versionsFrom('1.2.1');
  api.use(['cosmos:browserify@0.10.0'], 'client');
  api.addFiles(['wangEditor.browserify.js'], 'client');
  api.addFiles(['wangEditor.browserify.options.json'], 'client');
});

// Specify npm modules
Npm.depends({
  'wangeditor':'2.1.12'
}); my wangEditor.browserify.options.json ->{
  "transforms": {
    "envify": {
      "NODE_ENV": "production",
      "_": "purge"
    }
  }
}

Comment: i will appreciate for you reply

Comment: @user5699596 can you make another question?  it is hard to see the code in the comment. and comment section is not for answering neither

Comment: i add a quesetion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37758973/meteor-js-cosmosbrowserify-error-using-an-npm-module-write-a-package-user-npm-m